# On GTA Online, how do I cancel a heist?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've just completed the 'Prison Break' heist and chose to replay it, thinking I could just replay the final mission, and realised that I'd have to do all the setup missions. How do I cancel a heist? Will the next heist still be available to me? I seriously do not want to go through the Prison Break set up missions again. I'm on Xbox 360 (AS741).

Answer (score 6):

To cancel a heist, you need to call Lester.  The option to cancel the current heist will be there. He will then call you later in the game session to allow you to start the latest heist that you have access to.

Please note that canceling a heist after paying the setup fee will forfeit that money.

Answer (score 0):

To do the next heist you have to complete the heist before. And normal if you press continue, you go back to free mode.